# Who is the user for the shell spawned from shell function

Tags: linux, shell, makefile

In a makefile I have the following statement:

```
PLATFORM_LIBGCC := -L $(shell dirname `aarch64-none-elf-gcc $(c_flags) -print-libgcc-file-name`) - lgcc
```

and this reports an error:

```
aarch64-none-elf-gcc unknown command
```

This happens because the shell function executes the command under the root environment, which is not the user who runs the makefile.

**How can I invoke the shell with the environment inherited from the makefile?**

Comment: Makes always runs shell commands using the environment inherited from the process that ran `make`.  It does not (and cannot) escalate to `root` by itself. If things are executing as `root`, it's because you're running `make` as root.

Comment: Please make sure to copy-paste complete and unmodified error messages (hand writing the relevant parts is [not enough](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough)). What does `type aarch64-none-elf-gcc` say in your shell?

Comment: I think there are too many open questions here. Please show the relevant code, how the make command is being invoked, and state the exact error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Note that the code inside of the backticks will be executed BEFORE the `$(shell ...) ` command is completed/run, so it's not actually the `shell` command that's failing.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry - Regarding _completed_, you're of course right; regarding _run_, that's not so; try: `strace -feprocess make`, it shows e. g.
`execve("/usr/bin/make", ["make"], [/* 46 vars */]) = 0˿
[ Process PID=12659 runs in 32 bit mode. ]˿
vfork(Process 12660 attached˿
)                                 = 12660˿
[pid 12660] execve("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh", "-c", "dirname \`aarch64-none-elf-gcc  -"...], [/* 47 vars */]) = 0˿
`.